# XNA -perform rotations and transformations on individual bones through code

Tags: c#, xna

I am using fbx file format with xna framework without skinnedprocessor.

I followed some of the post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791845/xna-rotate-a-bone-with-an-offset-translation) regarding the rotation or translation of individual bones for creating gestures in human body. I used the XNA sample for display of fbx model, i was even able to move full body left and right.

Now my problem is I wrote  a code for rotation of some valid bone, but just normal model is getting displayed instead of model with rotating bone 9.

This part of code was written in skinnedmodelprocessor.cs

```
   List<Matrix> bindPose = new List<Matrix>();
   List<Matrix> inverseBindPose = new List<Matrix>();
  List<int> skeletonHierarchy = new List<int>();

     foreach (BoneContent bone in bones)
            {
                bindPose.Add(bone.Transform);
                inverseBindPose.Add(Matrix.Invert(bone.AbsoluteTransform));
                skeletonHierarchy.Add(bones.IndexOf(bone.Parent as BoneContent));
            }

 //code for updating the position of a particular bone
        int idbone = 9;
    bindPose[idbone] = bindPose[idbone]*Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f));
```

This is my draw method
 
 *protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);*

```
            Matrix[] bones = animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms();

            Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -40, 0) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(camerarotation))
                          * Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc))
                          * Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraArc), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);

            Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1, 10000);
         //Looping over multiple meshes
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in firstmodel.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones);
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = worldtransformations[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                    effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f);
                    effect.SpecularPower = 16;
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
}
```

Its look like I screwed up somewhere.

I have three models for first and third models error pops "no skinning data", but i loaded everything (texture, changed content processor).

Second model just gave blank screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When asking questions, just assume that you will need to post your code and describe the specific issues you're facing with what you've done so far.  We can't be of much help otherwise.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: "i am ready to share my code if needed." -- Yes, you should do that. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience caused by my way of writing. Now i edited the post and i request you  to have a look.